# How to use a cycle in the sql query with php?

Tags: php, sql

I need to configurate a user's feed showing the posts by users which first user following.
Like Instagram feed. I have a `posts` table. There is `author_id` column. In API request we have `requester_id` POST param.
And we have the second table named `relations`(following, followers).
There are just two column - `follow_by` and `follow_to`.
How do I can get posts by users `requester` following with SQL request with PHP.
It means in `relations` must be a row there `follow_to = author_id(from post)` and `follow_by = requester_id`.
Sorry for some mistakes(eng).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should perform a Subquery:

```
<?php
if($sq = $mysql_connection->query('SELECT `follow_by` following, `follow_to` followers, `author_id` id FROM `relations` WHERE `author_id`=(SELECT `author_id` FROM `posts`)')){
  if($sq->num_rows){
    while($row = $sq->fetch_object()){
      // each row now has the following attributes within the loop
      // $row->following // $row->followers // $row->id
    }
  }
  $sq->free();
}
$mysql_connection->close();
?>
```

Of course, if you are using client information to do you MySQL queries you'll want to prepare your statements.